# Restrict members to add new row

Tags: permissions

I want to restrict members of SharePoint  list to add new rows however they can edit the existing ones.

I tried using permissions however its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon.
I would do like this. Would go to the main page in Site Settings => Site Permissions => Permission Levels. And there I would create a new group of permissions. And there it will already be possible to choose what is allowed and what is not. Including editing the material BUT do not add a new one[image]